# Regular Conditional Probability vs Regular Conditional Distribution

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, geometric-measure-theory

Wikipedia (and different books too) seem to give two different definitions of what a **regular conditional probability** is. What is the correct definition and how do they relate? It seems to me that the first definition is the correct one, while the second is actually the definition of a **regular conditional distribution**?

Definition 1 can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Measure-theoretic_formulation).

> **Definition 1**: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{F}$. Let $\mathbb{1}_{\mathsf{A}}:\Omega\to\{0, 1\}$ be the indicator random variable. A conditional probability of $\mathsf{A}$ given $\mathcal{G}$ is defined as a version of  $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\mathsf{A}} \mid \mathcal{G}]$ and denoted $\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A} \mid \mathcal{G})$
> $$
> \int_{G} \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}\mid \mathcal{G}) d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}\cap G)  \qquad \forall \, G\in\mathcal{G}. \qquad \qquad \qquad (1)
> $$
> A conditional probability is said to be regular if $\mathbb{P}(\cdot \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega)$ is a probability measure for any $\omega\in\Omega$. Essentially it is a markov kernel satisfying condition $(1)$.

Definition 2 can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability#Formal_definition). This involves an additional random variable $X$.

> **Definition 2**: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(E, \mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space, and $X:\Omega\to E$ be a random variable with distribution $\mathbb{P}_X = X_*\mathbb{P}$. Let $\nu:\Omega\times\mathcal{E}\to [0, 1]$ be a markov kernel satisfying
> $$
> \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}\cap X^{-1}(\mathsf{B})) = \int_{\mathsf{B}} \nu(x, \mathsf{A}) \,d \mathbb{P}_X(x).
> $$

In general, I could not find anywhere the difference or relationship between **regular conditional probability** and **regular conditional distribution**

Comment: To relate these two, take $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(X)$ in definition 1. I think you get definition 2?

Comment: See also Durrett, page 214 (Section 4.1.3 "Regular conditional probabilties") which defines both regular conditional probabilities and regular conditional distributions: https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf

Comment: I think your equation (1) has a mistake and it should be $P[A \cap G]$ not $P[A \cap \mathcal{G}]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is a more general definition. If you take $X$ to be the identity map from the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ to the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})$ you recover the first definition; with $\nu(x,A)=\mathbb{P}(A\,|\,\mathcal{G})(x)$, $\mathbb{P}$ a.e $x$.

Added:

1. (Distribution) Conditional distribution is a term that makes sense for a triple $(X,\mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})$, where $X$ is a random variable $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to (E,\mathcal{E})$, $\,\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathbb{F})$. The $\mathbb{P}$-conditional distribution of the random variable $X$ is an assignment to each $B\in \mathcal{E}$, an RV represented $\mathbb{P}$ a.e by the function $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_B\circ X\,|\,\mathcal{G}]$.
2. (Density function) For $A\in\mathcal{F}$, $$m_A(B)=\int_\Omega \mathbb{1}_A\cdot\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_B\circ X\,|\,\mathcal{G}]\;d\mathbb{P},$$ where $B\in\mathcal{E}$, is a measure on $(E,\mathcal{E})$. Denote the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $m_A$ w.r.t $X_\ast \mathbb{P}$, $\nu^\mathcal{G}(\cdot,A)$.
   Call $\mathbb{P}$-conditional probability density function of the random variable $X$ with respect to the measure $X_\ast \mathbb{P}$, the assignment to each $A\in \mathcal{F}$, of an RV represented $X_\ast\mathbb{P}$ a.e by the function $\nu^{\mathcal{G}}(\cdot,A)$ (the kernel in the question posted if $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(X)$).
3. So the conditional probability density function and conditional distribution carry the same information.
4. (Probability) Conditional probability makes sense for a pair $(\mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})$ where $\mathcal{G}\subset \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. The $(\mathbb{P},\mathcal{G})$-conditional probability on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is the assignment of an RV represented $\mathbb{P}$ a.e by $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A\,|\,\mathcal{G}]=:\mathbb{P}[A\,|\,\mathcal{G}]$, to each $A\in\mathcal{F}$.
5. They are extensions respectively of the notions of $\;$"distribution of a random variable", "probability density function of a random variable" and "probability" (with the trivial conditioning $\mathcal{G}=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$) to general $\mathcal{G}\subset \mathcal{F}$.
6. As for all $B\in\mathcal{E}$,
   $$\int_\Omega \mathbb{1}_B\circ X\cdot\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A\,|\,\mathcal{G}]\;d\mathbb{P}=\int_\Omega \mathbb{1}_A\cdot\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_B\circ X\,|\,\mathcal{G}]\;d\mathbb{P}=\int_E \mathbb{1}_B\cdot \nu^{\mathcal{G}}(x,A)\;d(X_\ast \mathbb{P})(x),$$ if $X=id:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to (\Omega,\mathcal{G})$, with $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$, then $$\nu^{\mathcal{G}}(\omega,A)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A\,|\,G](\omega),\; \mathbb{P} \;\text{a.e}\; \omega\in\Omega.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes sense that the first one is a special case of the second one. However, what is the definition of conditional probability distribution then?

Comment: I expanded the answer.